# Marshalling double parameters with P/Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, c++, interop, pinvoke

I have a problem with a P/Invoke call I'm trying to do. I have to call a C++ class from a C# program. I have the source of this class so what I did is put it in a DLL project and create export functions to access it's main method. That should be enough to do what I need and keep things simple.

My export method looks like this :

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void Inference(double *c1, double *c2, double *c3, double *result)
{
    /* somecode */
}
```

This compiles, and I can see the export in a `dumpbin` output.

Now the problem is, I can't call this method from my C# code because I always get a `PInvokeStackInbalance` exception, telling me that

> This is likely because the managed
>   PInvoke signature does not match the
>   unmanaged target signature.

I tried calling the method with this :

```
[DllImport("InferenceEngine.dll")]
extern static unsafe void Inference(double *c1, double *c2, double *c3, double *result);
```

I also tried this :

```
[DllImport("InferenceEngine.dll")]
extern static void Inference(ref double c1, ref double c2, ref double c3, ref double result);
```

... which were both possible ways documented on MSDN but with no luck. Does anyone have any clue about what the problem is ?

Thanks !

Comment: You cannot 'call a C++ class' from C# code.  It doesn't look like one though.

Comment: `ref double` or `out double` are the correct ways to declare the parameters -- don't start using `unsafe` if you can help it

Comment: Hans : Yeah the extern function is not a class but it actually calls the class. I just did a simple functoin to make the calling from outside simpler.

Comment: Tim : I know unsafe code should be avoided but I just wanted to try that as i was out of ideas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your C++ function as `__stdcall`, which is the P/Invoke default:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Inference(double *c1, double *c2, double *c3, double *result);
```

It's also possible to leave the C++ prototype alone and change the P/Invoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("InferenceEngine.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

`cdecl` isn't used often with P/Invoke, probably because the Windows API is `stdcall`.

Comment: Or use CallingConvention in the [DllImport] attribute.  Use Cdecl.

Comment: @Hans, you're one step ahead of me :)

Comment: Looked like *you* were one step ahead of *me*.  These partial posts are a pita.  But yeah, they do get you votes and medals I guess.